# Character limitations on RFID tags

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers

Is there a limit to the number of charectera that can be encoded and read in an RFID tag?
Using a Zebra ZT610 printer and Zebra Designer. Tags that we are testing with are 448 bits for EPC and over 600 for User. We have alternated between each memory bank for our testing. The ZPL code shows that they are encoding with the full 17 characters in ASCII but when we read them, it is truncating the numbers. We are using VIN numbers so we need to use ASCII.
Reading with 123RFID on a zebra device.
Thanks in advance. I can’t post the code as I am away from the office.

Expecting the full 17 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Tags have what is referred as Protocol Control (PC) bits which is a 16bit word that is part of the tag’s EPC memory. Those bits control how the tag should utilize its EPC memory and they are usually set for a 96bit EPC.

You can read here for more detailed explanation - https://www.atlasrfidstore.com/rfid-insider/uhf-rfid-epc-memory-bank-what-is-the-crc16/

You will need to modify the PC bits as part of your label ZPL. Here is an example on how to change the PC bits to support 240bit EPC and write a new tag value:

`^XA^RFW,H,1,2,1^FD7800^FS ^RFW,H,2,30,1^FD112233445566778899001122334455667788990011223344556677889900^FS^XZ`

You can read more about the solution here - https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Defining-The-Size-Of-The-EPC-Data-That-Can-Be-Encoded-For-GEN2-RFID-Tags?language=en_US